# Storing/Reading json data in iOS

Tags: ios, json, data-storage

Is there a limit in storing JSON data in iOS local storage and later read the JSON data for offline viewing? I don't want to use localstorage HTML5 or SQLite, since it's easier and faster to store it in JSON file and faster to load.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what are you asking about. But if you dont't want to store the json data using SQLite, you can use the `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:jsonData forKey:JSON_DATA_KEY];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

And then read from it:

```
NSData *jsonData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:JSON_DATA_KEY];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If coding a native app, the limit is just the available space on the device.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the input.